# Borderless printing on DIN A6

Tags: paper, printing, cardboard

For my project I would like to print small cardstock cards (250-300g/m^2) roughly size of DIN A7. Now it is almost impossible to find paper and printers for that format, so I figured I will use DIN A6 and print two on one and use a cutting board to separate.

But I couldn't find any printers claiming to do borderless DIN A6 - its mostly only photo formats in 10x15cm (which is almost DIN A6) but I can't really find white cardstock/cardboard cards in that format, all paper in that format is geared towards photos and not suitable (I need sturdy cardboard like cards and compromise on print quality).

Anybody has tipps or printer recommendations that would allow to print borderless onto DIN A6 at those paper weights? I wonder if any "overprinted" ink that remains in the printer could damage it / smear onto next prints.

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts.  Can you clarify the issue with photo paper?  That's available in different weights and finishes.  Printers that handle borderless prints are typically configured to print to the edge of standard sized photo paper.  Otherwise, oversized paper is normally used and then trimmed.  Also, when you say "roughly" A7 size, is there a specific dimension you need that you can trim from A7, or do you just need something close to that size (in which case, what would be the dimension limits on the finished items)?  Would there be an issue with more units per sheet?  (cont'd)

Comment: Would significant wastage be an issue; is this huge runs or small quantities?  Have you looked at US-sized standard-dimension sheets?

Comment: My old Epson photo printer (Stylus photo r300) can do borderless 10x15, borderless A4 *and pretty much anything in between*. I would expect that to normally be the case for printers that can do borderless A4, but of course the software may try to be too clever

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to print 2 cards on DIN A6 and cut the excess off, why don't you print even more cards on A4 and then cut them out? A4 is the standard paper format and there are *tons* of different printers that can print borderless A4 and *tons* of papers and cardstock in A4 with different weights, colors, finishes and other properties.

You don't even need to print borderless A4, if you're OK with losing some paper as cutoff. Evenly space your motifs on the available paper and then add cut markers **outside of the actual motif** to help you cut every card to precisely the same size without leaving any outlines on the cards.

There are some very good tutorials available for designing business cards, like [this one that explains the cut markers](https://www.castleprint.co.uk/design-business-card/) I mentioned:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually that is my fallback solution. I just wanted to keep the cutting to a minimum (I need 100+ cards) and such that all cards end up in the same size in the end.

Comment: @Dynalon There might be paper cutting stances available in that size. I've seen different sizes being used in photo shops where the pictures are printed slightly bigger than standard size and then cut to size with a single press of the hand.